# Why CSS3 Animation is not working?

Tags: html, css, css-animations

Can someone help me to find out why animation on `<h5>` element doesn't work?

```css
#hero h5 {
  animation: fadein 2s;
  -moz-animation: fadein 2s; /* Firefox */
  -webkit-animation: fadein 2s; /* Safari and Chrome */
  -o-animation: fadein 2s; /* Opera */
  font-weight: strong;
  font-size: 28px; 
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<section id="hero">
    <div class="content">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <h5>Lorem Ipsum Demo Title</h5>
            </div><!-- row -->
        </div> <!-- container -->
    </div> <!-- content -->
</section><!-- section -->
```

Comment: maybe its working.check again

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't work https://fiddle.jshell.net/f2c6L0ut/

Comment: i checked crome and firefox and its working but not in fiddle.

Comment: OK thanks, in this case why it may not work for me? I'm preparing a pure HTML file with a couple of styles (preparing via Bootstrap 3)

Comment: is it  not working in your browser ?

Comment: Where you have defined `fadein` animation?

Comment: Yep, no browser works correctly with this (Chrome, Mozilla, Opera)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You are calling `fadein` animation in your code but you haven't defined it anywhere.

CSS3 animations are defined with `@keyframes` rule. More Information about CSS3 animations is [Here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp).

Add following css:

```
@keyframes fadein {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```css
#hero h5 {
  animation: fadein 2s;
  -moz-animation: fadein 2s; /* Firefox */
  -webkit-animation: fadein 2s; /* Safari and Chrome */
  -o-animation: fadein 2s; /* Opera */
  font-weight: strong;
  font-size: 28px; 
}

@keyframes fadein {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<section id="hero">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <h5>Lorem Ipsum Demo Title</h5>
      </div><!-- row -->
    </div> <!-- container -->
  </div> <!-- content -->
</section><!-- section -->
```

Comment: Oh, I really forgot about it. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 4):

```css
#hero h5 {
     font-weight: strong;
     font-size: 28px; 
 -webkit-animation-delay: 0.7s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 0.7s;
  animation-delay: 0.7s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn { from { opacity:0; } to { opacity:1; } }
@-moz-keyframes fadeIn { from { opacity:0; } to { opacity:1; } }
@keyframes fadeIn { from { opacity:0; } to { opacity:1; } }

.fade-in {
  opacity:0;
  -webkit-animation:fadeIn ease-in 1;
  -moz-animation:fadeIn ease-in 1;
  animation:fadeIn ease-in 1;

  -webkit-animation-fill-mode:forwards;
  -moz-animation-fill-mode:forwards;
  animation-fill-mode:forwards;

  -webkit-animation-duration:1s;
  -moz-animation-duration:1s;
  animation-duration:1s;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<section id="hero">
        <div class="content">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                <h5 class="fade-in">Lorem Ipsum Demo Title</h5>
 
                </div><!-- row -->
            </div> <!-- container -->
        </div> <!-- content -->
</section><!-- section -->
```

Answer (score 2):

You must define a animation named `fadeIn` - as shown below.

Currently, you are using an animation but you have never created it.

```css
@keyframes fadeIn {
    0% {
        transform: translate(0,0)
    }
    30% {
        transform: translate(5px,0)
    }
    55% {
        transform: translate(0,0)
    }
   80% {
        transform: translate(5px,0)
    }
    100% {
        transform: translate(0,0)
    }
}
```